# Parse text file columns to show data based on time

Tags: python, file, parsing, text

My text file is generated by a Python script that writes:
[timestamp],[energy],[distance]

This the is data from the lightning strikes.

I would like to run a bash or a python script that would load and parse this text file and output:
A) number of strikes last hour (actually how many rows in a file belonging to timestamps in the last hour)
B) number of strikes every hour of the day (same as above but would output 24 values)

My example text file looks like this:

```
2017-05-24 16:29:20,5937,12
2017-05-24 16:30:14,950,12
2017-05-24 16:30:44,3242,12
2017-05-24 16:31:19,2615,12
2017-05-24 16:51:41,8723,24
2017-05-24 18:19:51,5166,27
2017-05-24 18:40:44,1521,37
2017-05-24 18:53:27,9309,24
2017-05-24 18:57:29,13760,20
2017-05-24 19:02:38,35905,12
2017-05-24 19:03:57,3349,12
2017-05-24 19:04:11,4935,12
2017-05-24 19:04:39,14361,12
2017-05-24 19:07:44,2726,12
2017-05-24 19:08:04,6399,12
```

I can adjust the time format of the text file to write [Y],[m],[d],[H],[M],[S] if it is easier to work with it later.
I'm new to Python so any hint is appreciated. I don't know how to get started.
Thanks

Comment: What form do you want this to take in Python? A list of tuples? A dictionary of columns? A pandas dataframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way you can load it and generate consistent output.
Assumption: Each text file will only hold 24 hours of data!

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import csv
import datetime

d = {n: 0 for n in range(1,25)}

with open("lightning.txt", "r") as f:
    filer = csv.reader(f)
    for i in filer:
        d[datetime.datetime.strptime(i[0],"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").hour] = (datetime.datetime.strptime(i[0],"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), i[1], i[2])

for i in range(1,25):
    if d[i] == 0:
        print(str(i).zfill(2) + ':\t0')
    else:
        print(str(i) + ':\t' + str(d[i][2]))
```

Comment: Hey, this is it! Thanks man! I mean to both of you that helped. I really appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

To begin, read in the file, loop through with `file.readlines()`, and then use `.split(',')[0]` to pull off the timestamps.

Then look into the [datetime module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) – I think the `datetime.strptime` method will help. e.g.:

```
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime("2017-05-24 19:04:11", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
datetime.datetime(2017, 5, 24, 19, 4, 11)
```

From there, you can build a data structure that relates your data to datetime objects, and then sort them by `datetime.hour`.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I'm successfully parsing the data. Now I have to see how to generate the files I need for plotting.

Comment: If you feel that this answer successfully addressed your question, please click the checkmark to accept it, so that others don't think the question still needs to be answered :)